# WPF How to load Items inside ContextMenu without open it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try to get **MenuItem** from **ContextMenu**. If I open context menu at least once it works fine, otherwise I get error ItemCollection has no inner collection. As I understand this behavior is caused by ItemSource binding. How can I load **Items** without manual open context menu?

**XAML:**

```xaml
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100">
        <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Rectangle.ContextMenu>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding GetMenuItemCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainContextMenu}"
            Height="30" Width="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel:**

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<string> Items { get; }
    public MyCommand GetMenuItemCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<string>()
        {
            "a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"
        };

        GetMenuItemCommand = new MyCommand(GetMenuItem);
    }

    public void GetMenuItem(object obj)
    {
        var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)obj;

        // Here I get exception
        var item = contextMenu.Items[0] as MenuItem;
        var header = item.Header
    }
}
```

**MyCommand**

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;

    public MyCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;


    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        execute?.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It is demo code, I'm not following MVVM approach here

**EDIT:** Full exception message: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid while ItemCollection has no inner collection. ItemCollection is uninitialized or binding on ItemsControl.ItemSource supplied null for collection.'

**EDIT 2:** As people mentioned in the comments, probably purpose of getting MenuItem is not clear, so I introduce more details.

I'm trying to write helper class, that will merge child context menu with parent menu if needed. I do not know anything about context menus I will merge. I am currently trying to copy elements from parent menu and add them to child menu, when child menu is opening. For that reason I need to create new MenuItem, copy properties from parent's MenuItem and add this new MenuItem to child's context menu. My solution works fine, but only when parent menu was opened at least once.

I already asked straight question about merging context menus, but got no appropriate answers, so there I tried to ask something different.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to get that item from the context menu instead of just accessing the list itself?

Comment: There is `MenuItem` until the `ContextMenu` has been opened actually. But why don't you simply access the item in the `Items` (`List<string>`) collection?

Comment: @jeanluc162 yes, I want to create helper for merging two context menus, so I need to copy elements from one menu to another. I don't know how context menus will look like, so in one case I can bind Header to datacontext property, in another case I can bind to xaml property. To get header I need to access MenuItem

Comment: @mm8 maybe I do something wrong, but until I open ContextMenu I do not have any items inside Items property. About your question - please check my answer to jeanluc162

Comment: It looks wrong indeed. You didn't show a complete errror (try searching for topics with it). It's not clear what you want to do by looking at this method, so no good suggestion/workaround either.

Comment: @Sinatr thank you, I will edit question. GetMenuItem is called from Button, I bind Command property to GetMenuItemCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* no `MenuItem` until the `ContextMenu` has been opened. And passing a `ContextMenu` to a view model breaks the MVVM pattern.

You should get the underlying data value from the source collection instead of trying to access the eventually created visual element. The MVVM version of your code looks something like this:

```
public void GetMenuItem(object _)
{
    var item = Items[0];
    ...
}
```

Obviously a view model cannot create additional `MenuItem` elements. It may add more `strings` to the source collection though.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I add Edit sections to the question, and explain why I need to access MenuItem.

Comment: If you want to "copy MenuItems", you should clearly not do this in a view model because then it's no longer a view model...

Comment: And again: There *is* no `MenuItem` until the `ContextMenu` is open. They are created on demand.

Comment: about ViewModel: Inside NOTE I wrote that this code is just simple demo and I do not follow MVVM, but anyway, thank you for the help, if there is no MenuItem until the ContextMenu is open, I would try something different